# how to dismiss the keyboard and textFieldShouldReturn not getting called

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard, uitextfielddelegate

Basically `textFieldShouldReturn` is not getting called. 
I have seen lots of examples using .Xib but thats not exactly the same as I am using Storyboards and a newbie on ios.

So I have basic view Controller with 1 text field.

the ViewController is like:

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *test;
@end
```

So I am using the UITextFieldProtocol.

Then in the .m file I have

```
@synthesize test;
```

and inside viewDidLoad I have

```
self.test.delegate = self;
```

Then I have implemented the method:

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *) textField{
NSLog(@" I am being called");
return YES;
}
```

So this method does not get called when I click on the textfield despite setting it as the delegate.

Is there something in Xcode 5 storyboard that is required?

Comment: That method is called when the text field has focus and you then tap the Return button (or whatever its label) on the keyboard.

Comment: You can select the UITextField in the storyboard and ctrl+drag the connection to the UIViewController to set the delegate for the UITextField. Also, you can remove the @synthesize as properties are now automatically synthesized (under certain circumstances).

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer and its easy you dont need to even use Protocols etc !!

So everything I did in the code (which is common code that you will find on the internet) will not work on Xcode 5. That code does not run.

Instead of you want to have a callback method if user clicks on a textField you do not need to use UITextFieldDelegatw at all.

Instead inside your Controller create a IBAction like:

```
-(IBAction)textFieldReturn:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"text field Return");


}
```

Then inside of the StoryBoard Select the "Connections Inspector" and select the TextField that you wish to assign that controll to.

Then in Special Event drag the "TouchDown" to the textfield and select the method that you have just created. In the case above you will be presented with textFieldReturn option.

And thats it.

Now when you run the application when you select that check box you will get the call back.